# Define a function inside an js object works but don't know why

Tags: javascript

Why is the c function inside object works, Isn't it should be  `c: function(){}` like the other items?

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c(){},
};
```

Comment: Do you want to run the function outside object1 ?

Comment: That is just an alternate (*short*) syntax of `c: function(){}` 
Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects#defining_methods

Answer (score 1):

Both notations are correct. `c(){}` is equivalent to `c: function(){}`, it is just a shorthand notation to define methods.

defining a method:

```js
const object = {
  a: 'Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.',
  b: 42,
  c: function() {
    return this.b;
  },
};

console.log(object.c());
```

shorthand notation:

```js
const object = {
  a: 'Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.',
  b: 42,
  c() {
    return this.b;
  },
};

console.log(object.c());
```

For realy leasy people, you can do it `shorter` with the arrow-notation, when you need to return a value:

```js
const object = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: () => object.b,
};

console.log(object.c());
```

---

**Update** Be careful with the `this` operator.